# Oracle Deleting rows from a table based upon rows in a temp table

Tags: oracle, temp-tables

I have a table like so:

```
PermTable
Col1 Primary Key
Col2 Primary Key
Col3 Primary Key
Other rows
```

I am loading data from a file into a temp table with basically the same structure as the PermTable:

```
TempTable
Col1 Primary Key
Col2 Primary Key
Col3 Primary Key
Other rows
```

I want any rows in PermTable that do not exist in TempTable to be deleted from PermTable

The SQL I am using is:

```
DELETE FROM PermTable WHERE NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT NULL FROM TempTable
    WHERE TempTable.Col1 = PermTable.Col1
     AND TempTable.Col2 = PermTable.Col2
     AND TempTable.Col3 = PermTable.Col3 )
```

This is not working.  It is deleting more than it should.

Comment: Your table definition should mention *column* and not *row*. Also a working example with relevant data would help us understand what is deleted that should not be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to just truncate the PermTable and insert all the temp records into it?

TRUNCATE TABLE PERMTABLE  --removes all records
INSERT INTO PERMTABLE (SELECT * FROM TEMPTABLE) --the structures the same...

Especially since you are replacing the contents of permtable with temp table?

Comment: I cannot as the perm table is an aggregate of other tables.  Each time the temp table is loaded for import, it is only a subset of the data in the perm table.

Comment: This statement in your question then is a little misleading:  "I want any rows in PermTable that do not exist in TempTable to be deleted from PermTable"...  Is this really what you want?  If so, you are REPLACING PermTable with TempTable.  I'm thinking your goal is something different.